# Getting the size of a query

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I'd like to fetch the size (number of records) of a query as efficiently as possible.

The query is a "GREATER THAN -date-" style query, and I would like to efficiently estimate how many records there are in the query in a cost efficient way. This does not have to be an accurate value actually, just an estimate. But a precise size would be better obviously.

The resulting size will be asked for very frequently. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way in app engine to do this accurately is to do a count query on your desired range. Yes, this will result in one small-op per result, but it will work.

Once you have established the general count in this way, you could use techniques to determine the frequency of counts based on date range length or other factors (i.e., day of month, etc.). Then you could use these guesses to estimate without querying anything. Obviously, the quality of the estimation is determined by how accurate the model you create is.

Comment: Sorry. There used to be a limit of a 1000 on count, but now there isn't. A count query will give the correct value, but you're responsible of the cost! I agree, simply doing a count() is actually the best way. I'm only doing to do it once a day as well.